# How to create ImageView within an Asynctask?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I'm creating a web application running an asynctask. Using JSoup, each time the code loops through an image within a div container I want my code to create an ImageView object in which I will place certain images in the OnPostExecute method.

For instance I have this page : https://www.flagrantdelit.ca/lever-le-voile/

I'm able to get all the text from the div class="entry-content" but each time my code loops through a p tag containing an Image I want to create an ImageView that will contain that same image. I need to keep the same format as the website.

I tried checking for null text within a p tag and then creating an ImageView but it give me this error :
ImageView
(android.content.Context)
in ImageView cannot be applied
to
(com.example.leflagrantdlit.ArticlesFocused.DownloadData)

```java
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: Ended downloading AsyncTask");

            tvFocused = findViewById(R.id.tvFocused);
            tvFocused.setText(stringBuilder);


        }


        private String downloadHtml(String urlPath)
        {

            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlPath).get();
                String title = doc.getElementsByClass("entry-title").get(0).text();
                Elements pContent = doc.select("div.entry-content > p");
                Elements imgContent = doc.select("div.entry-content > p > img");


                for (Element textContent : pContent)
                {
                    if(textContent == null){
                       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this); 
                    }
                    stringBuilder.append(textContent.text());
                    Log.d(TAG, "downloadHtml: " + textContent.text());
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");

                }


                //String title = doc.getElementsByClass("entry-title").get(0).text();
                Log.d(TAG, "downloadHtml: " + urlPath + title + stringBuilder);


                return null;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "downloadHTML: Invalid Url " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "downloadHTML: IO Exception reading data: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "downloadHTML: Security Exception. Need permission? " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
```

For example, I want to place this image in this part of the paragraph.

![img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3DOQ.png

Comment: You want to create a model that is technically a list of items based on which you feed a RecyclerView.Adapter that will render the correct number of layouts which do contain an ImageView. You don't want to generate the ImageViews by hand directly.

Comment: I already have a feed and a ListView.Adapter but how could I create that specific layout if I dont know where the ImageView will be placed on the layout ? For instance I have paragraph,paragraph,ImageView, paragraph. It could be in that order or any order depending on the webpage I click on.

Comment: Two different item types? Also I said RecyclerView, not ListView